# Passing additional parameter in __index metamethed, Lua

Tags: lua

```
local T = {}
local m = {}
m.__index = function(self, i, par) -- here "par"
   self[i] = setmetatable({},{__index = function() return (par) end}) -- return "par"
   return self[i]
end

setmetatable(T,m)

for par=1, 3 do
   for j=1, 3 do
      for k=1, j do
         T[j][k] = T[j][k](par) -- pass "par" to __index metamethod
      end
   end
end
```

I am trying to pass "par" to __index metamethod that is changed by for-loop. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `__index` metamethod only accepts `table, key` parameters. [See PiL for details](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is posible without passing par in __index metamethod.

```
local t = {}
local m = {}
m.__index = function(self, i)
    self[i] = setmetatable({}, {__index = function() return function(r,k) return r*k end end})
    return self[i]
end

setmetatable(t,m)

print(t[1][1](12, 12)) -- passing "12, 12" returns "12*12", 144
```